# How do I see if some folder is a child of another using NSURL?

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsurl

I have an `[URL]` which represent a set of special parent directories. I am given another `[URL]` which represents files scattered around the system. I want to know if any of these files are in any of my special directories, or any of their subdirectories. **Is there a simple/intended way to do this, without manually parsing/traversing an absolute URL's path?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A slightly improved, Swift 5 version combining nice features of both Umair and rmaddy's existing excellent answers.

Like Umair's answer, this correctly handles the case where a folder in the path is a partial match (that is, it will not say that `/foo/bar-baz/bang` has `/foo/bar/` as an ancestor).

It also performs the canonicalization (standardizing paths to eliminate things like `.` or `../`, and resolving symlinks) like rmaddy's answer.

```
func pathHasAncestor(maybeChild: URL, maybeAncestor: URL) -> Bool {
    let ancestorComponents: [String] = canonicalize(maybeAncestor).pathComponents
    let childComponents: [String] = canonicalize(maybeChild).pathComponents

    return ancestorComponents.count < childComponents.count
        && !zip(ancestorComponents, childComponents).contains(where: !=)
}

func canonicalize(_ url: URL) -> URL {
    url.standardizedFileURL.resolvingSymlinksInPath()
}
```

Here's a very simple unit test to verify the basic functionality:

```
import XCTest

class FileUtilsTests: XCTestCase {
    func testPathHasAncestor() throws {
        let leaf = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/foo/bar/baz")
        let parent = leaf.deletingLastPathComponent()
        XCTAssertTrue(pathHasAncestor(maybeChild: leaf, maybeAncestor: parent))
        XCTAssertFalse(pathHasAncestor(maybeChild: URL(fileURLWithPath: "/foo/bar 1/baz"), maybeAncestor: parent))
        XCTAssertFalse(pathHasAncestor(maybeChild: leaf, maybeAncestor: leaf))
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very good! It takes the philosophy behind [Umair's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62440303/453435) and makes it more reliable! I think I'll use this as an `extension` on `URL`

Answer (score 6):

There's no method in `NSURL` that lets you see if another `NSURL` represents the root path of the other.

One possible solution is to convert the two URLs to path strings using the `path` property. Then see if one string is the prefix of the other. But before getting the URL's path, use both `URLByStandardizingPath` and `URLByResolvingSymlinksInPath` to ensure a consistent result.

Example:

```
NSURL *specialURL = ... // a URL for one of the special parent directories
NSURL *fileURL = ... // a URL for one of the files to check
NSString *specialPath = [specialURL.URLByStandardizingPath.URLByResolvingSymlinksInPath.path stringByAppendingString:@"/"];
NSString *filePath = fileURL.URLByStandardizingPath.URLByResolvingSymlinksInPath.path
if ([filePath hasPrefix:specialPath]) {
    // This file is in this special directory
}
```

Comment: You need to add a trailing slash to `specialPath` before the prefix test or else something like `/super` will be treated as a parent of `/supermarket/qfc`. (`NSURL`s `path` property strips any trailing `/`.)

Comment: @CRD Good point, thanks. Updated. Oddly when you print the `NSURL` of a file path representing a folder, the trailing slash is shown. But the result of `path` does not include the slash.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/../questions/43193772/ vs http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43193772/how-do-i-see-if-some-folder-is-a-child-of-another-using-nsurl But I have no better solution.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the prefix solution is that it would fail in cases: eg.

```
PathA: /Documents/untitled folder (1)/SomeFolder/Xyz/Waterfall.mp3
PathB: /Documents/untitled folder
```

The prefix solution will tell you that the PathA is child of PathB, although that's not the case.

A manually traversing solution:

#### Swift:

```swift
extension String {
    func isChildPath(of path: String) -> Bool {
        self.count < path.count
            && !zip(URL(fileURLWithPath: self).pathComponents,
                    URL(fileURLWithPath: path).pathComponents)
                .contains(where: !=)
    }
}
```

#### Objective-C:

```
@interface NSString (Additions)
-(BOOL)isChildOfPath:(NSString *)path;
@end
@implementation NSString (Additions)
-(BOOL)isChildOfPath:(NSString *)path {
   NSString * child = self;
   NSString * parent = path;
   NSArray<NSString *> * childPathComponents = child.pathComponents;
   NSArray<NSString *> * parentPathComponents = parent.pathComponents;
   if (parentPathComponents.count >= childPathComponents.count) {
        return NO;
   }

   for (NSInteger i = 0; i < parentPathComponents.count; i++) {
       NSString * parentComponent = parentPathComponents[i];
       NSString * childComponent = childPathComponents[i];
       if ( ![parentComponent isEqualToString:childComponent] ) {
           return NO;
       }
   }
   return YES;
}
@end
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer! It legit points out a very important concern! If I might, I looked over your Swift code and it's identical to this one-line version: `self.count < path.count && !zip((self as NSString).pathComponents, (path as NSString).pathComponents).contains(where: !=)` - would it be okay with you if I updated your answer with that? Also, creating a new URL out of them (using `URL(fileURLWithPath:)`) instead of bridging them to NSString has the same cost O(1), but works on Ubuntu.

Comment: Sure. You can edit and add this simpler version which is awesome.