# Check if a URL is a child of another URL

Tags: ios, swift, url

How can we check if a URL is a child of another URL.
example:
a file path is like:

```
file:///Users/me/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/folder1/myFile.swift
file:///Users/me/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/folder1/folder2/myFile.swift
file:///Users/me/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/myFile.swift
```

How can we check if it is a child of:

```
file:///Users/me/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply compare the string properties of given links:

If the format of your URL is `String` you can use it directly:

```
let str = "file:///Users/me/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/folder1/myFile.swift"
let root = "file:///Users/me/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices"

if str.contains(root){
  // code here
}
```

or as pointed out in the comments:

```
if str.hasPrefix(root){....
```

If the format is `URL` you can get the strings with:

```
.absoluteString
```

But be aware both are case sensitive.

Comment: Thanks! I think it is better to use ```hasPrefix```

Comment: Be careful with checking the prefix: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43193772/how-do-i-see-if-some-folder-is-a-child-of-another-using-nsurl